# Are Oracles useful in the mid game?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've seen Oracles being used in almost every game for early worker harass, but not as much as the game progresses into the mid/late game.

Do they have other uses in the game than just harassing workers for early pressure?

What tactics use Oracles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Revelation can be pivotal to prevent flanks on your army (especially that in the mid game, you don't have that deathstar of units yet, and you have to choose your engagements carefully).

Being able to detect can be useful, too, and Oracle harass in combination with Warp Prism harass (at 2 different location of course) can push the multitasking abilities of your opponent to the limit while allowing you to macro behind it.

Its ability to detect can be useful too if you don't want to lose robo building time on an observer.

**tldr;** If it's already built and you don't plan on harassing, yes. If you don't plan on harassing with it, don't build one just for revelation or detection in the mid game.

Answer (score 3):

If you can keep them safe from harm, Oracles pose a great use in assassinating key enemy units, such as seige tanks, ultralisks, spell casters, and even thinning out light size enemy armies.  Their Pulsar Beam does 15 dmg per .86 of a second. If you do the math thats 64.5 dmg in 5 seconds. Do that with just 3 Oracles and your talking about 181.5 damage. Oracles arn't horribly expensive at 150 gas and minerals. Think of them as a similar to mutalisks in terms of usefull-ness with numbers. They do an additional 10 dmg per beam-tic on light units as well, making them extremely more effective in that regard.

http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Oracle#Overview